# Web development dropdown list connecting to sql and shopping cart button

Tags: php, mysql, web-development-server

I'm currently adding a new functionality to a website in which it is a drop down menu that takes its options from mysql database and, as someone selects the wanted value, it updates and connects the right value to the 'add to cart button'.

So far, I have done the drop down list and I could get the data from sql and fetch it into the drop down list. But the problem is that I tried to connect the selected value from the drop down list to the 'add to cart' button with no luck.

I'm also trying to update listed the price as soon as the user selects a value from the drop down list. Here is the code I have done so far:

```
mysql_select_db("db name"); /// this the drop down list it works perfectly and displays items from mysql.

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT ProdID, ProdCatID, ID_AC_seperate, ProdImage, ProdName, ProdPrice, ProdShippingPrice, ProdShortDesc, ProdMediumDesc, suitable, cart_thumb FROM accessories WHERE ID_AC_seperate = 1 ORDER BY ProdID ASC");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql)){
$select= '<select name="select">';
while($rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){

$select.='<option value="'.$rs['ProdName'].'">'.$rs['ProdName'].'</option>';


 }
    } 

mysql_select_db($database, $data);// this is how it was done without dropdown list
$query_ac_list = "SELECT ProdID, ProdCatID, ID_AC_seperate, ProdImage, ProdName, ProdPrice, ProdShippingPrice, ProdShortDesc, ProdMediumDesc, suitable, cart_thumb FROM accessories WHERE ID_AC_seperate = 1 ORDER BY ProdID ASC";
$ac_list = mysql_query($query_ac_list, $data) or die(mysql_error());
$row_ac_list = mysql_fetch_assoc($ac_list);
$totalRows_ac_list = mysql_num_rows($ac_list);

if (isset($_POST["cart_1_ATC"]) || isset($_POST["cart_1_ATC_x"])) // this is adding to cart function for the previous code      {
  $ATC_itemID = $_POST["cart_1_ID_Add"];
  $ATC_AddIfIn = 0;
  $ATC_RedirectAfter = "../../shopping_cart.php";
  $ATC_RedirectIfIn  = "";
   if (isset($totalRows_ac_list) && $totalRows_ac_list > 0)     {
    $row_ac_list = WAEC_findRecordMySQL($ac_list, "ProdID", $ATC_itemID);
    if ($row_ac_list)     {
      $ATC_itemName = "".$row_ac_list['ProdName']  ."";// column binding
      $ATC_itemDescription = "".$row_ac_list['ProdShortDesc']  ."";// column binding
      $ATC_itemWeight = floatval("0");// column binding
      $ATC_itemQuantity = floatval("1");// column binding
      $ATC_itemPrice = floatval("".$row_ac_list['ProdPrice']  ."");// column binding
      $ATC_itemShipping = floatval("".$row_ac_list['ProdShippingPrice']  ."");// column binding
      $ATC_itemThumb = "".$row_ac_list['cart_thumb']  ."";// column binding
      mysql_data_seek($ac_list, 0);
      $row_ac_list = mysql_fetch_assoc($ac_list);
    }
  }


type="hidden" name="cart_1_ID_Add" value="<?php echo $row_ac_list['ProdID']; ?>" />
                        <input name="cart_1_Quantity_Add" type="hidden" value="1" size="1" maxlength="1" />
 <input name="cart_2_ATC" type="image" value="Add to Cart" src="../../WA_eCart/Images/S3A_AddToCart.gif" alt="Click to add this Portable AC to Cart" border="0" /> </td>
```

Comment: so you are trying to change the page data when an item is selected?

Comment: First. Stop using this deprecated API.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and were [**removed in PHP 7**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning). You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: @BrettSantore Yes, also I was trying to connect the drop down menu to the 'add to cart button'

Comment: @Strawberry yeah I know the site needs alot of work

Comment: @DaveP thank you DaveP I started this project recently I know it needs alot of updates.

Comment: This is not possible with the tech you've mentioned. PHP is server side you need client side knowledge to do this, JavaScript to be more specific.